# Iniciando um serviço do windows

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, services

Estou montando um "Monitorador de Serviço". Meu servidor windows está parando o serviço do meu banco de dados. Então montei um validador do serviço, mas não sei como dar o *start* no serviço de novo caso ele caia.

Esse é o código de até onde consegui chegar, a ideia é quando cair no `catch`, fazer o *start* no serviço MySql.

```
      while (true)
        {
            int contador = 0;

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
                conn.Open();
                contador++;

                if (contador == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(".");
                    contador = 0;
                }

                conn.Close();

                Thread.Sleep(30000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preciso fazer duas considerações:

1. Tentar conectar no banco para testar se ele está ou não funcionando não é a melhor abordagem. Existem muitos fatores que podem causar uma falha neste seu teste e começar a reiniciar seu banco de dados frequentemente sem motivo.

   - Nome de usuario ou senha inválidos;
   - Numero máximo de conexões simultaneas atingida;
   - Timeout; etc.
2. Este script está apenas tentando maquiar o problema, e não está resolvendo a causa.

Continue pesquisando a causa do problema, veja no *EventViewer* ou nos logs do MySQL. Mas não parta para fazer uma gambiarra dessa.

Sobre sua pergunta, para controlar um **Windows Service** voce deve usar a classe [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx).

Iniciar um serviço:

```
public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  var service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Parar um serviço:

```
public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  var service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Reiniciar um serviço:

```
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  var service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    var millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

    // count the rest of the timeout
    var millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2-millisec1));

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Fonte: [C# Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/)